# Dovecot mdbox to mbox/MailDir/eml conversion

Tags: dovecot, maildir, mbox

Is there any way to convert Dovecot's mdbox/dbox to mbox, MailDir or eml format (or any other easy to import format)?

Answer (score 0):

The dsync utility is intended to do this transformation.  If you have it installed you should have a man page that explains the options.  There is a section covering migrations such as you are looking for.

The process needs to be done per user.  Multiple runs are recommended.

From a quick review of the documentation it is possible to sync with a remote IMAP server.

It appears the Dovecot wiki is malfunctioning, but the Wiki documentation may be packaged with the install.  On my Ubuntu server it is in /usr/share/doc/dovecot-core/wiki.

Comment: If I understand good that wiki page it will migrate all mailboxes set at `mail_location` to desired format. How about converting only selecting mailboxes? Is it possible?

Comment: @JackTheKnife Depending on the folder stucture you should be able to point to specific folders and convert them.  You could also backup to an Maildir structure and delete the folders you don't want after the conversion.